# A generic converter in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter, boxing, unboxing

I have a converter in my WPF application, as follows:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Available?" 
                        Binding="{Binding Amount, Converter={StaticResource AmountToIsAvailableConverter}}" 
                        Width="*"/>
```

And the converter's code is as follows:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var amount = (int)value ;
    ......
}
```

I bind the column to the view-model's property Amount, which is of type int. The value of the above Amount property is transferred to the 'Convert' method of 'AmountToIsAvailableConverter' as the 'value' parameter (which is of type 'object'). Now, as far as I understand, a boxing has occurred here, because the int value is now treated as an 'object' type at the Convert method entry. That boxing operation has apparently occurred for nothing, because in the first line of my converter, I un-box the value and cast it back to int:

```
var amount = (int)value ;
```

Is there a converter in WPF with a Convert method that uses Generics?

```
public class AmountToIsAvailableConverter : IValueConverter<int>
```

So I could do something like that:

```
public object Convert(int value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{......}
```

The important part here is: `int value`

Is there a way to avoid the boxing and unboxing operations, other than adding an additional property in my view-model?

Comment: You cannot avoid boxing if you use databinding.

Comment: `Convert<int>(int ` is invalid syntax; that's not how generics work.

Comment: @SLaks You are right, I've edited my question. Suppose that T is declared at the class level.